# Renaming files in bash script using mv

Tags: linux, bash, mv

I recovered many MOV files from a faulty hard drive however software named these files as per block location:

**263505816.mov** etc...

I wrote a small script that uses mediainfo application so i can read date and time created and rename files accordingly:

```
for f in *.mov
do
    MODIFIED=$(mediainfo -f $f |grep -m 1 "Encoded date" |sort -u |awk -F "UTC " '{print $2}')
    DATECREATED=$(echo $MODIFIED |cut -d' ' -f 1)
    TIMECREATED=$(echo $MODIFIED |cut -d' ' -f 2 |tr -s ':' '-')

    mv $f "$DATECREATED $TIMECREATED.mov"

done
```

Which works fine but when i modify **mv** statement by adding 2 words at the end:

```
mv $f "$DATECREATED $TIMECREATED Holidays 2011.mov"
```

i get the following:

```
mv: target â  Holidays 2011.movâ is not a directory
```

I know i have to mark white spaces is some way because mv is mislead that it's a directory. Other articles do not mention using multiple variable in conjunction with mv that is why im asking for guidance.

Many thanks,

Comment: Sounds like `$f` contains spaces and is interpreted as multiple arguments, in which case the solution would be to quote it: `"$f"`

Comment: Also, I hope you have backups of your recovered files because this looks like a good way to lose all of them due to bugs in your shell script.

Comment: You can lose the `sort -u` after `grep -m1`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Unix.SE

Answer (score 1):

I think it worked the first time because `*.mov` expanded only to numeric files like the one in your example, but after the first execution of your script, it renamed the files introducing spaces in the form `$DATECREATED $TIMECREATED.mov`. Basically, the second time around, `mv` is attempting to move `$DATECREATED` and `$TIMECREATED.mov` to your target file, and since it's not a directory, it fails.

You can solve this by quoting `$f`. Try it like this:

```
mv "$f" "$DATECREATED $TIMECREATED Holidays 2011.mov"
```

In fact, it's recommended that you always quote variables unless you're sure they won't contain special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Before the `$DATECREATED` and after the `.mov` you have some characters that look like double quotes but are not so, my guess. Some typographic quotes. Try replacing with normal double quotes `"`. - in addition to the suggestion to also quote "$f" (with the right double quotes ;-)